Having a cell reference auto update when within an indirect reference
I have the following formula in Excel
 =IF(INDIRECT("'" & $S5 & "'!C8")="","",INDIRECT("'" & $S5 & "'!C8"))

It references S5 which contains "Alex" - this is the name of another tab I have called "Alex"
It also references C8, which is the cell in the Alex tab that I need to reference.
This works fine, however I have a macro that adds rows above cell C8 in the Alex tab - moving this cell down, but not updating the formula listed above.
I've tried a few different solutions with no luck. Tried incorporating a row() reference as well as an index() reference; however, the Indirect and Index formulas aren't ones I've got much experience with.

With this hard-coded reference to Alex!C8 this won't work. What could work is using index/match - that is, IF there is any unique row-identifier in the Alex sheet.

what's the error message/expected output?

Since INDIRECT function argument is a string it cannot be updated to the changes.
A workaround is (not too elegant, but works):

Create a sheet name Base
Add all the sheet names in column A as string
In column B place this formula =Sheet1!C8 for all sheets accordingly

After this applying this formula will follow the reference changes on the sheets:
VLOOKUP(S5,Base!A1:Bx,2)
Bx is the last address in the references is column B.
The Base sheet looks something like this:









Sheet1
=Sheet1!C8


Sheet3
=Sheet3!C8


Sheet2
=Sheet2!C8


Sheet6
=Sheet6!C8




I forgot to respond, however Sebastian's comment led me on the right trail.
The following formula is what I'm using now and it works nicely.
=IF(INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & $S5 & "'!C3:G1000"), MATCH($T$2, INDIRECT("'" & $S5 & "'!C3:C1000"), 0) + 2, 1)=0,"",INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & $S5 & "'!C3:G1000"), MATCH($T$2, INDIRECT("'" & $S5 & "'!C3:C1000"), 0) + 2, 1))

Cell T2 in this instance refers to a header exists on both tabs, and is being used as a reference point essentially.
Thanks a bunch!
